# VueJS does not fire input event on first input in IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I have an input with `@input="onInput"` set.

In the `onInput` method I output some console info (basically just `even.currentTarget.value)`. I noticed that in IE11 when I focus the input and then push any button (or use `ctrl+v`) once there is no output in console.

Then, on second try the handler is called and `event.currentTarget.value` has the whole string.

It happens only in IE11

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I set `placeholder` to a empty string. So actually I had a component which is a wrapper for `<input>`. In this component I had a `placeholder` property, which was set to empty string by default and was applied to `<input>` tag.

I set placeholder property to null by default and it helped

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved the issue and posted your solution. It will be helpful to other community members in future, If you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer after 24 hrs when it will be available to mark. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Done! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't have great support for the `input` event on some field types:

> `<select>` doesn't fire input events.
>   Doesn't fire an input event when (un)checking a checkbox or radio button.
>   https://caniuse.com/#search=oninput

and

> [IE] ignored the input event completely [on range inputs.]
>   Their change event behaved just like the input event did on other browsers
>    https://blog.vendivel.com/javascript/2016/01/31/ie-oninput-bug.html

The `keyup` event can be used as a substitute if you need per-key handling (though this doesn't support paste operations), or you can use the `change` event if you can wait until the user has finished entering data.

Comment: Turned out that I had empty placeholder which broke things. I have my own custom component for text inputs, and there was a placeholder prop which was set to empty string by default. I changed it to null and looks like it fixed the bug